# Issue using net-snmp (TypeError: p.charCodeAt is not a function)

Tags: angular, typescript, net-snmp

I'm trying to use net-snmp in my Typescript/.Net/Angular project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-snmp

I'm seeing a few errors when using net-snmp and looks like dependancy issues.  Any help appreciated:

When including the following code in the primary angular component:

`const snmp = require('net-snmp');`

I get the following error:

```
/ClientApp/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/util/path.js:85
        const c0 = p.charCodeAt(0);
                     ^

TypeError: p.charCodeAt is not a function
```

Any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot this?